# Incorrect date md-datepicker localization Thai language

Tags: angular, angular-material

With md-datepicker, when setting the Locale to 'th' (Thai) the year is incorrect.

Here is a Plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/6guQWJyfAUtEgPje9Tcd/

I set the locale in @NgModule using LOCALE_ID provider

Is there a problem with the way I'm setting the language?

Many other languages I've tested work as intended.

Comment: This is an Intl issue. Try the following in the browser console to see it
```var myDate = new Date();```
```new Intl.DateTimeFormat('th').format(myDate)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Intl issue. Try the following in the browser console:

```
var myDate = new Date();
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('th').format(myDate);
```

You will see "12/9/2560". This is because the Buddhist calendar is used by default. You need to switch it to the Gregory calendar. So, your locale should be `th-TH-u-ca-gregory`. You can use a function to add the required calendar to the locale returned by your browser:

```
function getLocale() {
  const locale = 'th';
  return `${locale}-u-ca-gregory`;
}

providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useFactory: getLocale }]
```

See the updated [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/9LpqAQyrvo0YhENYSmsv?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the plunk you linked is updated, but using 'th-TH-u-ca-gregory' works! In my production code I actually use navigator.language to get the locale, which returns 'th' when the browser is set to Thai, is there a way to get the Gregory locale instead? If not I can just write a function to replace 'th' with 'th-TH-u-ca-gregory'.

Comment: You are right. I've modified my answer. Yes, you can use a function to add the required calendar to the locale returned by your browser.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a problem with md-datepicker. The months are days are getting mixed up after selecting a date.

Comment: In my case, a date goes before a month. See http://take.ms/X6aNb. How does it work for you and how should it work?

Comment: Try selecting the same day. For today Sept 12 2017 will show as 12/12/2017, but the output will still be Sept 9.

Comment: Do you mean that the text inside the div element is not updated when you select a value in the date picker? You need to use two-way binding for ngModel: ```<input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]='myDate'>```